# Angular Unit test on click

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to writing unit tests in Angular.  I am trying to write a test to verify that dropdown menu opens when a button is clicked.  This is the relevant HTML:

```
 <button mat-button class="requestMenu" [matMenuTriggerFor]="requestMenu">Requests</button>
      <mat-menu #requestMenu="matMenu" yPosition="below">
        <button mat-menu-item>{{'dashboard.header.screen_options.action_required.option_text' | i18next}}</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>My Requests</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Assigned to Me</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Unassigned</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>View All</button>
      </mat-menu>
```

And this is what I have as far as a test goes:

```
it('should show request menu if "Requests" is clicked', () => { 
  expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.requestMenu')).nativeElement).toBe(false);
  const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.requestMenu')).nativeElement;
  button.click();   
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.requestMenu')).nativeElement).toBe(true);
});
```

I am getting the error: `Expected HTMLNode to be false.`  Can anyone help with this?

Here is the describe code.  It may be overkill, but I'm hoping it will furnish a clue:

```
   describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;
  let logger: LogService;

  class MockLogService {
    getData(): Observable<any[]> { return Observable.of([]); }
    debug() {
      this.writeDebug();
    }
    error() {
      this.writeError();
    }
    info() {
      this.writeInfo();
    }
    writeInfo() {
      return;
    }
    writeDebug() {
      return;
    }
    writeError() {
      return;
    }
  }

 class MockAppSandboxService {
   setMainProgressBar() {}
 }


  beforeAll(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
                                platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
  });

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        SearchBarModule,
        TestingModule,
        FormsModule,
        MaterialModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        SafePipeModule,
        EffectsModule,
        NgProgressModule.withConfig(env.progressBarConfig),
        I18NextModule.forRoot(),
        StoreModule.forRoot({})
      ],
      declarations: [
        NotificationsComponent,
        BadgeComponent,
        UsernameIconComponent,
        PreferencesComponent,
        HeaderComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        CustomIconService,
        SidenavService,
        { provide: LogService, useClass: MockLogService },
        { provide: AppSandboxService, useClass: MockAppSandboxService },
        [Store],
        Actions
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    logger = TestBed.get(LogService);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });
```

Comment: Post the related describe/it blocks. It looks like the error is not correct, how can the expectation error be false when you assert `toBe(true)` ?

Comment: Posted describe code above.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're asserting an Object is equivalent to `false`. You're also not grabbing the element you want to test the visibility of. I assume that your intention is to write a test that does the following:

1. Assert the element is not visible
2. Perform some action
3. Assert the element is visible

```
it('should show request menu if "Requests" is clicked', () => {
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#requestMenu'))).toBeFalsy();
    const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.requestMenu')).nativeElement;
    button.click();   
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#requestMenu'))).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Change your template to have an id on the element you're trying to toggle:

```
<mat-menu id="requestMenu" #requestMenu="matMenu" yPosition="below">
```

Comment: Now I am getting the error "Expected DebugElement({ nativeNode: HTMLNode, _debugContext: DebugContext_({ view: Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 1073733075, ..."

Comment: It sounds to me the test is legitimately failing now. I think your test was grabbing the wrong element.